# How to load large xml dataset file in python?

Tags: python, xml, directory, load

Hi I am working on a project in data analysis with python where I have an XML file of around 2,8GB which is too large to open . I downloaded EmEditor which helped me open the file . The problem is when i try to load the file in python google colaboratory like this :

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('dataset.xml')  //dataset.xml is the name of my file 
root = tree.getroot()
```

I get the result that No such file or directory: 'dataset.xml' exists . I have my dataset.xml file on my desktop and it can be opened using the EmEditor which gives me the idea that it can be edited and loaded via the EmEditor but I don't know . I would appreciate your help with helping me load the data in python 
google colab.

Comment: Shentos Try line by line. Here's an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61228553/what-is-the-best-way-to-use-xpath-for-processing-larger-xml-files/61378002#61378002

Answer (score 0):

Google Colab runs remotely on a computer from Google, and can't access files that are on your desktop.

To open the file in Python, you'll first need to transfer the file to your colab instance. There's multiple ways to do this, and you can find them here: https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb

The easiest is probably this:

```
from google.colab import files

uploaded = files.upload()

for fn in uploaded.keys():
  print('User uploaded file "{name}" with length {length} bytes'.format(
      name=fn, length=len(uploaded[fn])))
```

Although keep in mind that every time you start a new colab session you'll need to reupload the file. This is because Google would like to use to the computer for someone else when you are not using it, and thus wipes all the data on the computer.

Comment: Thank you . I'll try it now

Comment: Still 0% loaded.

Comment: When you press execute 
`!ls`
In a cell, does it show your file (potentially between other files)?

Comment: I used visual studio code to open the file in the end . I copied the file in my project path