# What is the best way to use Xpath for processing larger XML files?

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I have a requirement where I have to use an large XML (4 GB file) for finding values in it. Basically I have to write around 30 different Xpath and store the values in a list. When I try to parse an XML, it throws memory error. I have tried using lxml and ElementTree with start and end events, still no luck the processing time is too high and my Pycharm/Jupyter notebook throws me memory error.

Is there a better way to do it? Even though this implementation is not restricted to any programming language, I prefer Python because its my right hand. Thanks in advance.

Eg of a search: If I want the value of year where category is cooking. Then I use ./bookstore[@category=cooking]/book/year. So the value is 2005

Similarly I have to find the values of my tags based on my business requirements. In my requirement the XML is not simple as the below example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<bookstore>

<book category="cooking">
  <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
  <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>30.00</price>
</book>

<book category="children">
  <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
  <author>J K. Rowling</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>29.99</price>
</book>

<book category="web">
  <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
  <author>James McGovern</author>
  <author>Per Bothner</author>
  <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
  <author>James Linn</author>
  <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
  <year>2003</year>
  <price>49.99</price>
</book>

</bookstore>
```

Comment: There may be a better way of doing it; but it depends on whether the problem can be tackled using streaming. For that we need to know something of the structure of the file and the nature of the search you are performing.

Comment: @MichaelKay To be frank the XML is quite huge, I am unable to define the structure here. But basically its the combo of several nested tags. Wrt search I have explained it in my question now.

Answer (score 1):

With the example given, the problem can be readily handled using streaming in XSLT 3.0:

```
<xsl:mode streamable="yes">
<xsl:template match="book[@category='cooking']">
  <xsl:value-of select="year"/>
</xsl:template>
```

I know the example is a simplification, but we can only judge whether the real data/query is streamable by seeing the real data/query. The devil is in the detail.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will meet your needs. Try it first. If there is a problem, we can continue to communicate.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc,req,utils
def getBook(lines,category,year):
  html = "".join(lines)
  book = SimplifiedDoc(html).book
  if book.category==category and book.year.text==year:
    return book.category,book.title.text,book.authors.text,book.year.text,book.price.text
lst = []
with open('bookstore.xml', 'r') as file: # bookstore.xml is your xml file path
  lines = []
  flag = False
  for line in file:
    if flag or line.find('<book ')>=0:
      flag = True
      lines.append(line)
    if line.find('</book>')>=0:
      b = getBook(lines,'web','2003')
      if b: 
        lst.append(b)
        break # If you only want the first one, add a break
      flag = False
      lines = []
print (lst)
```

Result:

```
[('web', 'XQuery Kick Start', ['James McGovern', 'Per Bothner', 'Kurt Cagle', 'James Linn', 'Vaidyanathan Nagarajan'], '2003', '49.99')]
```