# Is there a good method to deal with very large XML files in python?

Tags: python, xml

Wikipedia full xml dumps are huge and the `iterparse` method in `ElementTree` doesn't cope well with the fact that there are 3 separate data fields all labelled `<id>`.

So I had the idea to pull out a useable section of the wikipedia XML everything between `<page>` and `</page>` and pass that into `ElementTree` which should be able to deal with the nesting.  The idea was to set a true/false flag when the XML page tags are encountered to control the flow and send out blocks of XML as a string.

This is my code, which doesn't do what I think it should!  Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

Many thanks!

```
page = None

page_element = ''

for line in fh:

    line.rstrip()
    if line.startswith('  <page>'):
        page = True
        print('True')

    elif line.startswith('  </page>'):
        page = False
        print('False')

    elif page == True:
        lines to a string
       
    else: 
        pass string to ElementTree
        clear string
```

Comment: Please provide a sample of XML and desired results. For larger XML look into [iterparse](https://effbot.org/zone/element-iterparse.htm).

Comment: You’ll need to explain what this code does, and what you want it to do.

Comment: The answer here is a bit similar to the approach you use. Maybe you can refer to it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61228553/what-is-the-best-way-to-use-xpath-for-processing-larger-xml-files